# Excel Insert Pictures into cell - center and set move and size - cells are changing and they are not fixed

Tags: image, vba, excel

I am trying to insert pictures in to my sales overview. I was looking for an answer online however I can't find simple solution any ware...

I have following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=picturefilename, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=picturecell.Left, Top:=picturecell.Top, Width:=75, Height:=75
```

Thing is that cells are not fixed, this a long loop and every time location will be different, furthermore cell is wider than a picture.

How can I center the picture in cell and change settings to move and size with cells without selecting the shapes? So without using "Selection" since the number of pictures is not fixed and will be different every time...:

```
Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
```

Or

```
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft (picturecell2.Width - Selection.ShapeRange.Width) / 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare this at the top

```
Dim Shp As Shape
```

and then use the `Shp` Object. For example

```
Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=picturefilename, _
                                        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
                                        Left:=picturecell.Left, _
                                        Top:=picturecell.Top, _
                                        Width:=75, _
                                        Height:=75)
```

You can create variables which you can use for Left, Top, Height and Width and include them in the loop.

Comment: Don't really have to use Excel at all but now I do for one single sheet and need to have check marks aligned in the middle of the column similar to this feature comparison chart `http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx`. Where do I add the script/code from the answer please? How do I make it so that the script centres the inserted picture (.png) automatically independent of the cell's width?

Comment: You will have to calculate the `Left, Top, Height and Width` at real time in the code @lowtechsun

Comment: When you say `calculate in real time` you mean I take the width of the cell where I want the picture centred and then take half of that value and then hard code that into the module? For ppl like myself doing this the first time look here `http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/code.htm`. Now I know where to put the code. So now I have found this script: `http://www.exceltip.com/general-topics-in-vba/insert-pictures-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html` Can I use that and it will automagically centre the picture in the column?

Comment: Ok, got done what I needed simply by selecting and shifting content by keyboard to desired posting, for what I needed to do this sufficed totally. Had the script going and constantly got errors, debugged and more errors, no time for learning all this. @Microsoft is it so hard coding simple image alignment into Excel, one would expect this is a basic feature, having to copy/paste 50+ lines of code to do this and then getting errors.. hmm. Like in the movie about Jobs when the guy says they cannot change font in a word processor. Freak out! Back to drawing board.. hmmm mmm.